# Could not find import for EnableOAuth2Sso annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I try to repeat following tutorial:

http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2

I have following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.2.RELEASE")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE')
}
```

And I have following class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    public class UiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
        }
    }
```

As you can seee I don't have import for `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation. And Idea doesn't suggest me import automcomplete.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced

```
 compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.2.RELEASE")
```

with

```
compile ("org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.0.RELEASE")
```

and Idea found import